# How to take the same cell from dozens of separate excel workbooks and insert into a "master" workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have dozens (probably hundreds) of workbooks with a standard format.  I want to pull specific cells from those workbooks, and put the values in a separate, "master" workbook.  The dozens of workbooks are unfortunately not named in a standard way (although I suppose I could just copy and rename them all) if that things easier.

Example: take B4:10 from workbook1.xlsx and workbook2.xlsx and workbook3.xlsx and put that data into Masterworkbook.xlsx in a "column for each workbook's values" type of way.

Comment: Ouch. You really should look into keeping a Database instead of sheets. In any case you could combine the sheets via move/copy. Here is a good place to start https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/456-combine-multiple-workbooks.html

Comment: Right, a database would be the real solution.  I'm coming in after the fact and trying to make the best of years of a very basic user community.  Combining all the workbooks into one would be a good start... then I would need to automate calls from sheets within a workbook....